# Can Dictionaries in Python be considered objects from C++ with only Data Members?

Tags: python, class, object, dictionary

I am studying Python right now and I am learning about Dictionaries. Is it correct to compare dictionaries with objects from C++ who only contain data members and no methods?

Of course there is not class definition so every object instance can be declared differently in Python, but still I think it i a good analogy to associate dictionaries with objects with no methods for the purpose of learning. Or is it something that I am missing here.

Comment: Dictionaries have methods.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did not know you could add methods to them... So this means that the similarity is even more strong.

Comment: I didn't say you could *add* more methods. I said dictionaries *have* methods. The `dict` class definition is not writeable, but you *can* subclass it.

Answer (score 3):

Is it correct to compare dictionaries with objects from C++ who only contain data members and no methods? **NO**

A dictionary is a data-structure which is analogous to `std::unordered_map`, though the implementation might differ.

An object is an instance of a class. Both C++ and Python supports Object Oriented programming to a large extent though there are differences which is out of scope of this answer. Off-course, both in Python and C++, either the `dict` or the `std::unordered_map` is implemented as a class which has methods and data-members.

In python though, `dict` is a type which inherit from `<type 'type'>`. Considering in python everything is an object, even if it a class or a function, it is too colloquial to talk about object when in Python world.

Answer (score 2):

All values in Python are objects, dictionaries included. Dictionaries have methods too! For example, `dict.keys()` is a method, so Python's `dict` instances are *not* objects with only data members.

There *is* a class definition for dictionaries; just because it is defined in the Python C code doesn't make `dict` any less a class. You can subclass `dict` if you need to add more methods, for example.

Comment: But if there is a class defined for dictionaries in python how can someone add all kinds of methods and data variables to it ? Are the new dictionaries created inheriting the structure of the dictionary class and adding more elements to it? I would be curious to see what is the definition of the dictionary class in Python code.

Comment: @yoyo_fun: why would a class need to be writable to be a class? And like all subclassing, any code using the parent class (`dict`) will not get the methods of a subclass, no.

Comment: @yoyo_fun The dictionary object source is written in C (for standard CPython); you can view the source code [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c).

Comment: Also, the phrase "everything is an object" should die. A statement is not an object. A keyword is not an object. Sure, a lot more things are objects than in Java, but beginners should know that probably you can't have a language where "everything" is an object.

Comment: @vlad-ardelean: all values are objects.